# Split an application template into module

Tags: angular, npm

As a member of the reference team for the new Angular 2 template in our company, we have take the decision to provide an Angular 2 template containing every useful package for the new project.

Currently, this template is a basic application with many component like:

- SpinnerModule (Spinnercomponent, SpinnerService)
- Menu (MenuComponent, MenuService)
- CustomHTTP (CustomHTTP extending HTTP)
- Etc...

To avoid the possibility of any edition on our global component, I would like to put every module on a NPM module (named @companyName/spinner, @companyName/menu). Is it the right approach?

Second question, I was thinking about creating a @companyName/shared module importing every others modules to ease the call. Is it a right thing to do, or not?